# Function and Basic Subprogram Distance Calculation

Tags: c++, function, prototype

I'm making a function that is supposed to display the values for distances from the sun in miles and scientific notation returned from a calcuation done into the subprogram to the main program. The resulting program builds and runs correctly, however it returns the wrong values that are supposed to be obtained. 
Here's what the output is supposed to be like, based on the code that was constructed before the function was added: [enter image description here][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJiKj.png
And the output I get now is about 4 times as much as that. 
Here is the code: 
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// -------------------------- Bode's Law Calculation --------------------------
//
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Name   : Bode's Law
// Version: 1.2b
// Purpose: Demonstration program to be used for 
//          examining output in scientific notation.
//          This program uses Bode's formula for 
//          estimating the distance between the Sun
//          and the planets in our solar system.
// Author : Jeffrey L. Popyack
// Date   : Jan. 20, 1998
// Modified: Mar. 3, 1999
//           Jan. 16, 2002 - names of constants changed
//           to agree with Horstmann style guidelines.
//           Feb. 2002, Feb. 2003 - reformatted internal layout
//
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <iomanip>
    using namespace std; 
    double estimateByBode(int n, double dist);
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// -------------------------------- Prototypes --------------------------------
//
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

//  Draw column guides up to NumColumns wide
    void columnGuides(int NumColumns) ;



// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// ------------------------------- Main Program -------------------------------
//
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    int main(void)
    {
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Bode's formula estimates the distance from planet n
    // to the Sun according to the following formula:
    //                   (n-2)
    //    dist = (4 + 3*2     )/10,
    // where dist is given in astronomical units, and
    // one astronomical unit equals 93,000,000 miles.

    // PLANET_2, PLANET_3, etc. are the names of the planets.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

        const string PLANET_2 = "Venus", 
                     PLANET_3 = "Earth" ,
                     PLANET_4 = "Mars" ;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  dist2, dist 3, etc. are estimated distances of
    //  planets from the Sun, using Bode's Law:
    //  e.g., dist2 is the distance from PLANET_2 to the Sun.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        int n = 1;
        double dist = 0;
        dist = estimateByBode (n, dist);
        double dist2 = estimateByBode(n,dist);
        double dist3 = estimateByBode(n+1, dist);
        double dist4 = estimateByBode(n + 3,dist) ;

        columnGuides(40) ;
        cout << "Planet  Astro Units (est.)  Miles (est.)" << endl;
        cout << setw(6) << left << PLANET_2.c_str() 
             << fixed << right << setprecision(3) << setw(11) << dist2 
             << scientific << setprecision(2) << setw(22) << dist2*93000000 
             << endl ;

        cout << setw(6) << left << PLANET_3.c_str() 
             << fixed << right << setprecision(3) << setw(11) << dist3 
             << scientific << setprecision(2) << setw(22) << dist3*93000000 
             << endl ;

        cout << setw(6) << left << PLANET_4.c_str() 
             << fixed << right << setprecision(3) << setw(11) << dist4 
             << scientific << setprecision(2) << setw(22) << dist4*93000000 
             << endl ;

        return 0 ;
    }


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// -------------------------- Subprogram Definitions --------------------------
//
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    void columnGuides(int NumColumns)
    {
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
       This procedure draws column guides of the form

                  1         2         3    
         123456789012345678901234567890123 ...
         ---------------------------------

         @param NumColumns - the desired column width  

    */
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

        int i ;

        for(i=1; i<=NumColumns/10; i++)
            cout << setw(10) << i ;
        cout << endl ;

        for(i=1; i<=NumColumns; i++)
            cout << i%10 ;
        cout << endl ;

        cout << setfill('-') << setw(NumColumns) << right << "-" << endl ;
        cout << setfill(' ') << resetiosflags(ios::right) ;
    }
    double estimateByBode(int n, double dist)
    {


        double estimateByBode = (4 + (3 * 2) * (pow(2, (n - 2))) / 10);
        return estimateByBode; 
    }
```

Comment: `(3 * 2) * (pow(2, (n - 2))` It seems the formula calls for multiplying `2^(n-2)` by 3, not by 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Titus-Bode law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titius%E2%80%93Bode_law) states

```
a = 0.4 + 0.3 * 2^m, for m = 0,1,2,....
```

which can be rewritten as

```
a = (4 + 3 * 2^m)/10
```

Your index might be off by one, and the code actually looks like someone was already fiddling around with it (why `2*3*2^(n-2)`??). I would suggest you to write

```
a = (4 + 3 * pow(2,n-offset);
```

and try different values for `offset`.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much for your help!!  It works now, decided to modify it the following way (in addition to changing the values to the correct values of n in the main program ie n +1, n+2, n+3): and the subprogram now reads: {

  n = n - 2;
  double estimateByBode = (4 + 3 * (pow(2, n))) / (10);
  return estimateByBode; 
 }

Comment: @marihikari dont forget to accept the answer, if this solved your problem